# How do I make methods look inside class for scoping before outside of class

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, scoping

Is it possible in Python - and if so how - to use definitions within a class as scope for its methods?
I am not talking about using the instances members using `self.` referencing, but really using the scoping mechanism?

So for example, while

```
class MyClass:
    def myfct(self, asdf=5):
        return asdf
```

or

```
asdf=5
class MyClass:
    def myfct(self):
        return asdf
```

work, the code

```
class MyClass:
    asdf = 5
    def myfct(self):
        return asdf
```

does not work. I am not sure why and whether I can use some clever trick or Python magic method to have force `myfct` to use the `asdf` inside `MyClass` - or in other words the scope of `MyClass` - *without* me writing

```
class MyClass:
    asdf = 5
    def myfct(self):
        return self.asdf
```

Comment: `def myfct(self): return self.asdf` or `def myfct(self): return self.__class__.asdf` or `def myfct(self): return MyClass.asdf` . Please check [class variables](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) in Python.

Comment: Why do you resist using `self.xxx` or `MyClass.xxx`  for accessing a class attribute?

Comment: [4.2.2. Resolution of names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names) ... [9.1 and 9.2 in the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-word-about-names-and-objects)